# Joining a list in python with different conditions and separator

Tags: python

I have a list of integer

`a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

and i must create a string with the integers separated by spaces and every five number i must add a '\n'

`string='1 2 3 4 5\n6 7 8 9\n\n'`

---

I have tried with a join like that:

`string=' '.join(a)`

but i don't know how to add '\n' with a condition.

Comment: Does the result need to be a 1 or 2 dimensional array?

Comment: you have a single `\n` after 5 digits then `\n\n` after 4 more digits- i don't understand this logic

Comment: See the duplicate on how to divide a list into chunks of 5. Join the contents of each chunk with spaces, join the chunks with newlines.

Comment: @antonio You could also do `from itertools import cycle; string = ''.join(str(item) + sep for item, sep in zip(a, cycle(' '*4 + '\n')))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use generator expressions to output the list in chunks for joining:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, a[i: i + 5])) for i in range(0, len(a), 5)))
```

This outputs:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9
```